# Why isn't this regular expression test working?

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have this

```
echo $line
Thisisaline.
```

I was wondering why is this not working:

```
if [[ "$line" =~ "[a-zA-Z]+\.$" ]] ; then echo "hello"; fi
```

Above regex gives no output.

Comment: Your regex pattern doesn't allow spaces, does it?

Comment: It doesn't, I modified the match string.

Answer (score 27):

The problem is that you are using quotes...

In bash regex, there is no need for quotes, and moreso, they should not be used (unless you are trying to match a quote (in which case you can escape it `\"`)... Also if you want a space in your pattern, you must escape it, `\`  (there is a space after the back-slash ...

Also note, that to match the entire line as being alphabetic, you must add a leading `^` and a trailing `$`, otherwise it will match such lines as: `123 456 abc. cat and mouse`

Answer (score 14):

Try

```
if [[ $line =~ [a-zA-Z]+\. ]] ; then echo hello; fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Some version of OS with bash gives you the output. So its up to you to get your updates.
However, without regex you can use extended globbing

```
shopt -s extglob
case "$line" in
+([a-zA-Z]). ) echo "hello";;
esac
```

if  not, use regex without the quotes

Comment: Yes +1, it is the quotes.. They are not needed, and moreso, should not be used here (unless you are trying to match a quote; so if you want a space in your pattern, you must escape it, `\ ` (there is a space after the \ ... Also note, that to match the entire line as alphabetic, you must ad a leading `^` and a trailing `$`, otherwise it will match `123 456 abc. cat and mouse`

Comment: @fred, ok, so you should put that up as an answer so OP can know. :)